# RadRails, Ruby, Content Assist and Methods

Tags: ruby, rubygems, aptana, radrails

I am new to Ruby, and I am currently working with an API which is unfamiliar to me.  In order to use code completion, which helps me learn, I installed RadRails in Eclipse.  However, I am having trouble with Content Assist: specifically, the Content Assist does not reveal the methods for objects in the API.

For example, one of my objects, ins, represents a loaded XBRL instance document.  If I run ins.methods, the list contains all of the methods I want, including those in the API (such as functions that allow me to access items in the instance):

...
item
item_all
item_all_groupby_vocab
item_all_map
item_by_vocab
item_ctx_filter
...
etc.

However, if I just type ins. with Content Assist enabled, it only shows options like:

dclone
gem
gem_original_require
JSON
Pathname(path)
...
etc.

which appear to be system options.  As a result, the Content Assist exposes exactly zero of the methods I actually want to use.  If I know the methods ahead of time and start typing them, I can get Content Assist to give them to me, eventually, by pressing Ctrl+Space.  However, that requires me to know what I want ahead of time; since I am using this to explore the API, that doesn't work for me.

Does anyone know how to get RadRails/Eclipse to show me the correct methods?

Regards,
Matt

Answer (score 3):

This is a general problem inherent to dynamic languages and IDEs/editors. The IDE has to guess at the type of the variable that the code assist is being invoked upon, and from that generate the list of applicable methods.

IRB has type information at runtime, so it knows what methods apply. The IDE is trying to guess the type by analyzing your code statically (not running it).

Having said that, the IDE should often be able to guess correctly. Providing the larger context of the snippet of code that this is being invoked on would be helpful to look into whether or not we could provide helpful content assist on this object. You may want to file a ticket with the version number, and the sample code here: http://aptana.com/r/apbugs

Comment: Thanks Christopher.  I will file a ticket and try to be more explicit.